# nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

This is my first time with nginx so please be gentle, i have two apache on two separate machines and a virtual host on each and i can access the pages from a LAN. i want to run nginx on another machine as a reverse proxy for them and do a load balncing for the two servers is that possible? and how the configuration will be like? i know i shouldn't ask this but i am new and i have been reading the basic nginx configuration from different sites but i couldn't understand anything, so basically i don't know how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

First you must set public ip or port forwarding from public ip, `port 80`, to your `nginx` server.

Then you must have connection between `nginx` and `apache 1`, between `nginx` and `apache 2` and between `apache 1` and `apache 2`.

```
                  | port 80 | prublic ip or fw from public ip
              -----------------------
              |        nginx        |
              -----------------------
             / 10.10.10.1           \
            / 10.10.10.2             \ 10.10.10.3
    |---------|                  |---------|
    | apache1 |------------------| apache2 |
    |---------|                  |---------|
```

Connection between `nginx` and `apache` is user for load balancing

Connection between `apach 1` and `apache 2` is for app replication.
You must have the same, synced, app on both `apache` node.

The following load balancing mechanisms (or methods) are supported in nginx:

`round-robin` — requests to the application servers are distributed in a round-robin fashion,

`least-connected` — next request is assigned to the server with the least number of active connections,

`ip-hash` — a hash-function is used to determine what server should be selected for the next request (based on the client’s IP address).
Default load balancing configuration

The simplest configuration for `load balancing` with `nginx` may look like the following:

```
http {
upstream myapp1 {
    server apache1.example.com;
    server apache2.example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        }
    }
}
```

More example of configuration and posibilitis you can find [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)

Comment: Then, accept answer